# Adding two columns from B to A and write new csv using R

Tags: r, csv

I want to merge two different csv files into one depending on one column. Both csv datasets have one column with the same description (name). Now I want to copy the content of two columns (`POINT_X` and `POINT_Y`) from Table B to Table A depending on the `NAME` column.

Every row of Table A with the name "TestTestTest" should have the corresponding values of Table B with the name "TestTestTest.

**TableA**

```
FID | NAME| job | school | superma | traffic | fun | shopping |
```

**TableB**

```
FID | NAME| pop | POINT_X | POINT_Y | POINT_Z
```

I've already tried to use the merge function.

```
newdata = merge(TableA, TableB, all="TRUE")
write.csv(newdata, file = "merge.csv")
```

This works somehow, but it writes a strange new .csv with many columns, which I don't want. I just want to add only the columns **"POINT_X"**, **"POINT_Y"** to TableA depending on the column **"NAME"**

Thanks!

Comment: you get your answers fast and best way if you can provide some reproducible example, ie subset of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could still use `merge`, but pass `tableB` limited to the columns `NAME`, `POINT_X`, and `POINT_Y`:

```
newdata = merge(TableA, TableB[,c("NAME", "POINT_X", "POINT_Y")], all=TRUE)
write.csv(newdata, file = "merge.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

merge is still the best way and you can add by parameter

```
newdata = merge(TableA, TableB, by="NAME",all="TRUE")
```

However, it can also be achieved as

```
TableA$POINT_X<-TableB[match(TableB$NAME, TableA$NAME),"POINT_X"]
TableA$POINT_Y<-TableB[match(TableB$NAME, TableA$NAME),"POINT_Y"]
```

Comment: Thanks! The second way is also very helpful.